# Session storage in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The value is correctly stored in the session attribute, but am encountering an issue when retrieving the session data.

```java
    @PostMapping("/setSessionValue")
    public String setSessionValue(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String value) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sessionId = session.getId();
        session.setAttribute(sessionId, value);
        System.out.println("value: " + value);
        System.out.println("session attribute: " + session.getAttribute(sessionId));
        return sessionId;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getSessionValue/{sessionId}")
    public String getSessionValue(@PathVariable String sessionId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String data = (String) session.getAttribute(sessionId);
        System.out.println("data: " + data);
        return "Value set in session: " + sessionId + ":" + data;
    }
```

when retrieving the session data am getting null

Comment: Hello, I suggest you to use this as a starting point. There are samples too : https://spring.io/projects/spring-session#overview

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a misunderstanding of Java EE `HttpSession`, so I suspect the code isn't doing what you intend.

You're using the `HttpSession` between calls and storing an object on it, which makes it available on subsequent calls from the same client. But your URL pattern looks more like an API than a web application, and APIs are normally "stateless", not using an `HttpSession` at all.

If this *is* an API and you *do* need to store state between these two calls, you'll need to make sure your API client stores and sends back the Session ID cookie. I would guess that this is the source of your problem, not connecting back to the original session, but starting a new one when you make the second call.

Which leads to the next issue. That is, you're storing on the `HttpSession` an object under the key of the Session ID itself, which is redundant. The Session ID is already the identifier into the JEE server's "map" of Sessions, so there's no reason you'd need to use the Session ID as a key into the Session itself. Instead, you'd use some descriptive string as the key to the object.

For instance, if your Session ID is `12345`, what you're currently doing is saying, "I'm session `12345`, get me an object with key `12345` from this session Map".

Instead, you'd use a key like:

```java
session.setAttribute("originalPostString", value);
```

And later:

```java
String data = (String) session.getAttribute("originalPostString");
```